# Calculate aws_volume_attachment ID using python

Tags: python, go, terraform, amazon-ebs

I'm updating a Terraform **state file** using **python(boto3)** so it can reflect existing resources in AWS, and I came across the resource **aws_volume_attachment** which only exist in Terraform, the ID is calculated using the hash of the following attributes: *instance ID, volume ID and the device name*.
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/73dbded87ea739a2fbcfd83150ac09633df659c0/builtin/providers/aws/resource_aws_volume_attachment.go#L244-L251

I tried executing the following so I can have the same ID as in the state file which in my case should be **vai-437263023**  but I'm getting **vai-3795101912** instead.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "hash/crc32"
)

func String(s string) int {
    v := int(crc32.ChecksumIEEE([]byte(s)))
    if v >= 0 {
        return v
    }
    if -v >= 0 {
        return -v
    }

    return 0
}

func main() {
    // Expected: vai-437263023
   //  Received: vai-3795101912
   var buf bytes.Buffer
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s-", "/dev/sdb"))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s-", "i-06754cada7514bb34"))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s-", "vol-028e997ae79e3a8ff"))

    fmt.Printf("vai-%d", String(buf.String()))
}
```

How can I get the same ID as in the state file? and how can I calculate the same ID but using python instead of GO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've checked a few provider versions and Terraform versions, and your code works well each time!

Python3:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.crc32(bytes('{}-{}-{}-'.format('/dev/sdb','i-06754cada7514bb34','vol-028e997ae79e3a8ff'), 'utf-8'))

3795101912
```

Also about that negative number check. It's `func ChecksumIEEE(data []byte) uint32` so it can only be a negative `int` on a 32-bit platform. Still, such platform would calculate your hash as 499865384, so it's not that corner case.